# Suggested exercises for learning with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I just got an arduino and have been working through some of the exercises in the tutorials, making good progress.

When I'm learning a new programming language or tool, I usually work through a few steps:

1. do the tutorials,
2. modify the tutorial programs, get them to do new stuff, and
3. solve a problem not covered in the how-to to make myself figure out how to do stuff.

With Arduino, I have a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem. I don't have a good enough idea what I *can* do with it to come up with interesting problems to solve.

What are some good problems/exercises I can tackle as a beginner to help myself learn more about what Arduino can do and how to do it?

Problem statements only, please. Any instructions for solving them would defeat the purpose (though, it might make sense to point out what hardware is required.)

Comment: There is a lot of strange and silly things that can be done with a Arduino, and hackaday is filled with strange example. Take the "fart o metet" as example: http://hackaday.com/2011/02/16/arduino-fart-o-meter/

Comment: possible duplicate of [I understand Arduino: now what?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/i-understand-arduino-now-what)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To learn what you **can** do we should start with hardware capabilities of
the platform. The Arduino (and other uC system that uses the ATmega328 or ATmega644) have a basic set of resources that are brought out to pins on the uC --

**digital inputs** - You use this to read a binary signal. A voltage greater than
around two volts is a one and less than 0.8V is zero. These are used to read 
the state of a binary device like a switch (mechanical, tilt, etc).

**digital outputs** Binary outputs. Use to turn on or off a device. LEDs, motors, etc.
With high current devices you usually need to add additional circuitry (like a transistor
or motor driver).

**analog inputs** These are used to read signals from analog outputs -- such as from 
a sensor. Low cost temperature sensors can have analog outputs, light sensors, etc.
The analog input converts the analog signal into a digital value that can be used
by your program.

**communications ports** To communicate to the outside world a UART is provided. This
enables you to send ASCII strings to an external device (most people convert the UART
to a USB port). There are two other protocols available -- SPI and I2C. These are
primarily used for communications within a system. Using these two communciations
interfaces additional capabilities can be added to a system such as high current
latches, analog outputs, real-time clock, SD storage. The list of SPI and I2C
peripherals is long.

I presented an "Intro to Microcontrollers" at the MIT Barcamp in 2009.
The handout is at --
http://www.luciani.org/not-quite-ready/not-quite-ready-index.html

Now that we have a summary of most of the capabilities what are your 
interests? Here are some example projects --

**robots** A lot of people do simple robots with their Arduino.

**art** A number of artists create interactive pieces with the Arduino. Add motion,
motion sensing, leds, sound

**music** You can create a numerically controlled oscillator (see http://wiblocks.luciani.org/docs/app-notes/nb1a-nco.html ). You could create
a midi device or an analog output sequencer that controls an analog
synth.

**datalogger** A number of people are doing datalogging applications. Temperature, humidity, light. Performance measurements for physical activity, etc. Energy monitoring.

**control** A number of people are doing CNC control with the Arduino or Sanguino.

If I were starting I would purchase a copy of "Making Things Talks" (MTT) from O'Reilly
and extend the examples. MTT works as a cookbook and a reference.

Answer (score 6):

The best beginners guide I have found is

http://www.earthshineelectronics.com/files/ASKManualRev5.pdf

Comment: the link is broken...

Comment: I think I found a working version: http://www.comp.dit.ie/dbourke/2%20Arduino_Beginners_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 5):

One suggestion is to get one of [Zach Hoeken's Danger Shields](http://www.zachhoeken.com/danger-shield-v1-0) from [the MakerBot Store](http://store.makerbot.com/featured-products/danger-shield-v1-0-1-kit.html) and try to do something awesome with it.  I used that to get started with the Arduino and going through its examples and modifying the code taught me a lot about interfacing with more than just LEDs.

For a problem you can try to solve, how about building your own special purpose PC keyboard that hooks into a PS2 port for controlling a game?

Answer (score 2):

You might find some of these articles [interesting](http://tronixstuff.com/tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

You should get a waveshield and make an xmas decoration that says 'braaaaainsss' when you push a button on santa's hat.  Or a different saying if you push his hands first.  How about that as a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer:

[I understand Arduino: now what?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/i-understand-arduino-now-what/4331#4331)